# Как обрезать строку на нужное кол-во символов начиная с последнего?

Tags: linux

Генератор выдает строки разной длины, требуется обрезать все до нужной длины, но при этом оставить нетронутыми концы строк, то есть обрезаться должны только начала строк, при этом соответственно задать позицию от начала, от которой должно обрезаться, ни определенный символ тоже невозможно, `cut` применить не получается, ну или какой-то мудреный синтаксис, мне не известный. Как вариант можно конечно инвертировать строки, обрезать и перевернуть обратно, но это на крайний. Как сделать на `awk` или `sed` может кто подскажет ? спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например:

```
$ echo 'stroka' | grep -Eo '.{2}$'
ka
$ echo 'stroka' | sed -r 's/.*(.{2})$/\1/'
ka
$ echo 'stroka' | awk '{print substr($0,length($0)-1,length($0))}'
ka
```

и [т.д. и т.п.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163481/110559)

Comment: alexander barakin, Вы лучший! спс